# 'Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type' - Vue 2, composition API problem

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm stuck after trying to add TypeScript to an existing Vue 2.6 project.
It has to stay at version 2.6 due to legacy reasons.
I have installed composition API as a plugin.

The error I face occurs on multiple components and is as follows:

```
Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This is my code:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { reactive, computed } from "vue";

export default {
  name: "Avatar",

  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "my title",
    },
    alt: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      default: "regular",
    },
  },

  setup(props) {
    props = reactive(props);
    return {
      classes: computed(() => ({
        avatar: props.title,
        "avatar--alt": props.alt,
        "avatar--small": props.size == "small",
      })),
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The problem occurs on the line containing `setup(props) {`.

Although adding type `any` to props in setup gets rid of error I know it is not the correct solution.

Do you have any suggestions or some solution to this problem?

Comment: Vue 2.0 doesn't have built-in Composition Api support. Use this package https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api

Comment: you can check [typescript option-api](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#typing-component-props) for more information on declaring components and syntax sugar. Vue is documented very well.

Comment: Oh sorry need to add this info to my question, composition api plugin is allready added :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue 2.6 doesn't  have composition api by default, I would suggest upgrading to vue 2.7 which includes it:

https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-2-7-naruto.html

if that is not possible and you are using the [vue 2 composition api plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api), chech that you are using the correct import:

```
// use the APIs
import { ref, reactive } from '@vue/composition-api'
```

Comment: Yes I can not change version unfortunately :/

Although it did not helped with the error, you were right I used wrong import with my composition API plugin, rookie mistake, thanks! :)